# Ocultar teclado virtual de Windows aplicación escritorio C#

Tags: c#, windows, wpf

Buenas, 
Primero que todo estoy trabajando en C# en realizar una aplicación de escritorio para Windows, con tecnología WPF.
Quería saber sí alguien conoce como se podría habilitar/deshabilitar el teclado virtual que aparece en las computadoras que tienen monitores táctiles (El panel que permite poner el teclado o activar escritura por medio de trazos).

Aquí adjunto la imagen del teclado virtual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí encontré la opción para habilitar o deshabilitar ese teclado (es la opción que dice "Use the Input Panel tab") desde las opciones de Windows, pero lo que quiero es poder hacer esta funcionalidad desde el código en C#.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo más que he encontrado es un artículo de [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms812266.aspx) (en inglés) en donde hablar de cambiar los registros en el sistema, para deshabilitar el pad de entrada de tablet, pero en verdad no logro relacionarlo con C#

De ante mano, agradezco la ayuda brindadar.

Postdata: Ya se que no aporto código, pero es que en realidad no tengo idea de como se podrá realizar esta funcionalidad.

Comment: Al habilitarlo te referís con que te lo muestre en pantalla? Process.Start("osk.exe");. En caso que quieras modificar alguna de las opciones que mostras en la imagen cual es?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que se habilite/deshabilite la opción de poder visualizar el teclado virtual. desde Windows, si le quitas el check a la opción "Use the Input Panel Tab", entonces ya el usuario no puede sacar el Teclado virtual de ninguna manera.

Comment: @RandallSandoval, puedes crear un archivo .bat desde código "como un .txt, pero lo guardas como .bat" cuyo contenido sea el valor de la clave de Registro; por código, lo que harías es ejecutar ese .bat; sin embargo, desconozco cómo ejecutar ese .bat y los valores correctos de Registro (debes tener cuidado en todo caso con las claves de Registro).

Comment: Cambiar o añadir claves de registro de windows desde c# es muy sencillo. Quizá lo primero que debes hacer es manualmente crear la clave en `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTIP\DisableInPlace` con la ruta de tu aplicación y ver si funciona. Si es asi, puedes añadir dicha clave desde tu aplicación,como se explica [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/h5e7chcf.aspx)

Comment: Conseguiste algo modificando la clase de registro @RandallSandoval?

Answer (score -1):

Prueba esto, este codigo lo abre y lo cierra, coloca dos botones y en el evento clic.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private OSK As System.Diagnostics.Process
Private Sub ButtonShowOSK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowOSK.Click
        'Create the OSK Process
    OSK = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe")
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonKillOSK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonKillOSK.Click
    Try
        OSK.Kill()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: hay un problema, no es la aplicación "osk.exe", lo que intento deshabilitar es el "input panel tab" que es el teclado que permite tanto teclado, como escritura por trazos.